# React Native :element type is invalid expected a string but got object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got this error and don't know where the problem is...
I am trying to import the header.js into the index.js

My index.js is:

```
//for ios application PLACE CODE HERE::::

//Import a library to help create a component
import React from 'react';
import { Text , AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/header';


//Create a component

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Header/>
    );
};

//Render it to the device

AppRegistry.registerComponent('yoyo', () => App);
```

And header.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const Header = () => {
    return <Text>Albums!</Text>;
};

export default Header;
```

Could anyone help me whats my wrong?

Comment: My index.js file in src?

Comment: Try 
`import React, { Text , AppRegistry } from 'react-native';`

Comment: @Shubham  still not working...if i export it through class then all is working fine..but not like this...i don't know why

Comment: Did you do the same in Header.js as well. I mean change the import

Answer (score 0):

Change your `header.js` by following.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Text>Albums!</Text>;
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: yes i already told that like this it works..but the above code is also correct..there should be an explanation why it is not working